# Request.Url.UserInfo No Value

Tags: c#, request

I request a URL as `https://user:pass@domain.com/etcetc`

In Controller, I use `Request.Url.UserInfo` get nothing, empty string, why?
Or, how can I get `user:pass` at controller

Comment: i've never known that to work with the HTTP[S] protocol...i've seen it with FTP, but not HTTP.

Comment: have you tries using `fiddler` to see what's really been sent?

Comment: Did you try it on production server?  
Maybe this field is ignored when no authorization is required by server?

Comment: yes, it send, I checked on fiddler, and also in production server, same thing. So maybe `Request.Url.UserInfo` always empty, M$ never init it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of things to check.

1) What does the raw url look like?
2) Validate that the UserInfo property works (which Microsoft says it does, and my tests show it does as well).

```
    Response.Write("Raw: " + Request.RawUrl);
    Response.Write("<br />");

    Uri uriAddress = new Uri("http://user:password@www.contoso.com/index.htm ");
    Response.Write("Test URL Results: "+uriAddress.UserInfo);
```

Based on my own tests I would guess that the user:password portion is being stripped out before it gets to your page.  In IE, as others have stated, I was unable to get it to take the values.  In Chrome it also seemed to strip them off automatically (after I had typed in the address and hit enter the values disappeared from the address bar immediately).

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489) may be your issue. IE does not support that by default.

Comment: I am using Chrome, and from console, it shows user:pass part has been sent to IIS